# How to select the first child of every div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to select the first div of several divs.

I have

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>good</div>
  <div class='child'>bad</div>
  <div class='child'>nice</div>
  <div class='child'>fun</div>
</div>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>test</div>
  <div class='child'>dead</div>
  <div class='child'>fly</div>
  <div class='child'>pipe</div>
</div>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>weee</div>
  <div class='child'>jump</div>
  <div class='child'>run</div>
  <div class='child'>apple</div>
</div>
```

I want to select the first child div of all parent divs

so

```
 <div class='child'>good</div>
 <div class='child'>test</div>
 <div class='child'>weee</div>
```

will be selected

I have tried:

```
1 $('.parent .child').first().css('border-top','0'); //only select the first one

2 $('.parent).each(function(){
     $(this).css('border-top','0');//can't find the first child..
  })
```

Are there anyways to do this? Sorry my brain is fried now. Thanks!

Comment: `$('.parent').children('.child').first()`

Comment: @adeneo That will select one element only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want...

```
$(".parent .child:first-child")
```

Comment: Right, people often forget that jQuery selectors are just like CSS selectors, and that's how you'd select it in CSS...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use jQuery if you like:

```
$('.parent .child:first-child').css('border-top','0');
```

...but I think regular old CSS is probably a better idea:

```
.parent .child:first-child {
  border-top: 0;
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the standard CSS nth-child selector:

```
$('.child:nth-child(1)')
```

This selects every element with class `child` that is the first child of its parent.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".parent .child:eq(0)")`

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rpMGE/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent :first-child').css('border-top','0');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NMH3h/